# xml.etree writes xml to file in an unexpected manner

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, utf-8, xml.etree

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse and alter a utf-8 xml file. 2 of the issues are because the file is written in Unix file format instead of Windows. Issue 1 is obvious, line endings are `\n` instead of `\r\n`. Issue 2 is that utf-8 strings are being rendered differently because of the different file formats (I assume). How can I force the `write()` function to save in Windows file format? I currently use `write()` like:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import sys

    altSpellingTree = ET.parse(sys.argv[2])
    altSpellingRoot = altSpellingTree.getroot()
    recordList = altSpellingRoot.findall("record") # Grab all <record> elements and iterate
    for record in recordList:
        # Check for the existence of an <alternative_spelling> element
        alt_spelling_node = record.find("person").find("names").find("alternative_spelling")
        if alt_spelling_node == None:
            continue
        else:
            # Check if <alternative_spelling> element text is solely ","
            if alt_spelling_node.text == ",":
                alt_spelling_node.text = None # Remove the lone comma
    altSpellingTree.write(sys.argv[2], encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

The third issue is that the file that is output uses self-closing tags where there used to be an opening and a closing tag (ex. `<Country></Country>` becomes `<Country />`). Is there a way to keep this from happening?

-------EDIT--------
Here's are 2 samples how the XML looks before the program is run:

```
    <Country></Country>
    <Category_Type></Category_Type>
    <Standard></Standard>

    <names>
      <first_name>Fernando</first_name>
      <last_name>ROMERO AVILA</last_name>
      <aliases>
        <alias xsi:nil="true" />
      </aliases>
      <low_quality_aliases>
        <alias xsi:nil="true" />
      </low_quality_aliases>
      <alternative_spelling>ROMERO ÁVILA,Fernando</alternative_spelling>
    </names>
```

And the same 2 samples after the program is run.:

```
    <Country />
    <Category_Type />
    <Standard />

    <names>
      <first_name>Fernando</first_name>
      <last_name>ROMERO AVILA</last_name>
      <aliases>
        <alias xsi:nil="true" />
      </aliases>
      <low_quality_aliases>
        <alias xsi:nil="true" />
      </low_quality_aliases>
      <alternative_spelling>ROMERO ÃVILA,Fernando</alternative_spelling>
    </names>
```

Comment: can you post part of your xml and your output, and what you expect to see?

Comment: Yup. I got it working in C#, now I'm just confused why python won't cooperate with me.

Comment: one thing I notice, after you parse `altSpellingTree`, you never modified it and just `write` at the end...

Comment: I thought that by traversing down to the `<alternative_spelling>` tag, checking if the value is equal to ",", and removing if true that the tree would be updated as well. Is this not the case? It seems to be working in a different step of my program, that modifies another XML file.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code if there is any bug, but to avoid self-closing tag, change this:

```
altSpellingTree.write(sys.argv[2], encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

to

```
altSpellingTree.write(sys.argv[2], encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True, method="html")
```

should do the trick.

And to much simplify your code, you can use `iter` to search your **tree**
Something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('your.xml')

for el in tree.iter('alternative_spelling'):
    # check your el text or whatever
    if el.text == u",":
        el.text = ""
    print el.text
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I never thought to add that param. Indeed, this fixed the self-closing tags issue, but the others still remain. However, I think they both have to do with the same thing (saving the file in Unix file format instead of Windows).

Comment: as you write your file into `utf-8`, I don't think the format should be an issue either on  Unix/Windows. It's more likely what **xml reader** you read and render the xml file itself :)

Comment: I see, I'll keep looking into that then.

Comment: as you mentioned earlier, you may be from C# background which means likely using Visual Studio, which itself has a bad behvaiour on some "hidden" character.

Comment: It took a while, but I actually got the C# in VS2010 to play nicely with utf-8 encoded xml.

Comment: lol how ironic, i used to have a bad time debugging a doc edited by a colleague using VS and found out a bad character was injected after saved.
To the point with `\n\r`, since you're only altering the `node` of `alternative_spelling`, there is nothing to do with line breaks. So again it's how your xml reader behaves that actually matters